# How do you filter array of objects in react using setState?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple array of objects but I can't seem to update state with the filtered values. If you console.log() the filteredData variable, the data is filtering correctly. However if I use the same variable inside setState() the filtered results aren't returning when console logging the people array. Does anyone know why this is happening? I'd also like to be able to re-render the list of filtered results. Do I need to use .map() inside the setState() method?

Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            people: [
                { id: uuidv4(), name: 'dave' },
                { id: uuidv4(), name: 'bryan' },
                { id: uuidv4(), name: 'abi' },
                { id: uuidv4(), name: 'chris' },
            ],
            text: ''
        }
    }
    handleSearch(e) {
        const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase() 
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ text: value }));
    }
    render() {
        const { people, text } = this.state;

        const filteredData =  people.filter((person) => {
            return person.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
        })

        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="searchPeople" placeholder="Search..." onChange={ this.handleSearch } />
                <ul>
                    {
                        filteredData.map((person) => (<li key={ person.id }>{ person.name }</li>))
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const root = document.querySelector('#appRoot');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

Comment: Since you don't need `prevState`, I suggest trying `this.setState({people: filteredData});`

Comment: setState is asynchronous so your state may be updating , you are just logging it earlier. You can use a callback function to log your state like this.setState({people: filteredData},()=>console.log(people));

Answer (score 0):

Edit both setState to retain the previous state unchanged  properties this way:

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  people: filteredData,
});

this.setState({ ...this.state, filters: { text: value } });
```

Comment: `this.setState({ ...this.state` is unnecessary, it does a shallow merging.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Cybershadow mentioned in the comment above, **setState** is asynchronous. And your log is being triggered before the value in `this.state.people` changes i.e. logged the previous state value. **You can use a setState callback function to make use of the changed data state after a setState update is completed.** And to use the setState callback, you need to pass the callback function as an second argument to the `setState()` method. In your case something like this:

```
this.setState(
 {people: filteredData},
 ()=>console.log(this.state.people) //callback
);
```

More on React's [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I've used your code exactly, however the array is still empty when console logging and I have no idea why. I've also tried console logging inside componentDidUpdate() but again the array is still empty when it should return a single matched object

Comment: In that case, maybe the `filteredData` is empty. Have you tried logging the `filteredData` value too? I mean to say, here - `let filteredData = people.filter((person) => person.name.toLowerCase() === value);`, this filter statement might be returning an empty array.

Comment: I've updated my example code see render() method. I can only seem to get the desired functionality if I filter the data inside the render method and store the filtered data in a new variable which isn't what I was expecting or think is very elegant. To my knowledge I thought I could filter the data inside a setState() method, this would update the this.state.people array and the people.map() would automatically re-render the updated array values from state or have I got that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@mjwals as setState is non concurrent the refreshed state will not be accessible quickly, so you can compose a callback work in the setState strategy inside the callback you will get the refreshed state, so from that point you can do other activity with the refreshed information. genuinely take a look at the code underneath

```
import React from 'react';
import "./styles.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      people: [
        { id: uuidv4(), name: 'dave' },
        { id: uuidv4(), name: 'bryan' },
        { id: uuidv4(), name: 'abi' },
        { id: uuidv4(), name: 'chris' }
      ],
      text: ''
    }
  }
  handleSearch(e) {
    const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
    this.setState({ text: value }, () => {
      const { people, text } = this.state;
      const filteredData = people.filter((person) => {
        return person.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
      })
      this.setState({ people: filteredData })
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { people } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Please enter a input to search</p>
        <input type="text" name="searchPeople" placeholder="Search..." onChange={this.handleSearch} />
        <ul>
          {people.map((person) => <li key={person.id}>{person.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```